# How to save and restore data that has some features are lists?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a tabular dataset like:

```
            Feature 1 (String), Feature 2 (Int), Feature 3 (List of String)
Record 1:
Record 2:
...
```

I store it as .csv. However, I found it is not convenient to restore the data of Feature 3. An example of restored feature 3 of a record: `['(abcd, 0)', '(dwg, 1)', '(sdgwa, 7)']`. It is a list of items. Each item has a string and an integer, written in a bracket.

I drop the [ and ] of this String, and try to split the remained as a list. However, the coma also appears within each item. What is the recommended practice to store such kind of data with lists?

Comment: You might try storing as JSON instead. That has no problem storing structured data like lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always solve this problem with either JSON or pickle and dictionaries.

If you go with JSON:

```
import json
my_json = {f1: "some string", f2: 100, f3: [100, 50, 10], f4: ['hello', 'blah']}
log = open("outfile.json", "w+")
json.dump(my_json, log)
log.close()

#to load it back:
log = open("outfile.json", "r")
my_jsons = json.load(log)
log.close()
```

You can also use pickle and dictionaries:

```
import pickle
my_dict = {f1: "some string", f2: 100, f3: [100, 50, 10], f4: ['hello', 'blah']}
pickle.dump(my_dict, open("outfile.p", "wb" ))

#to load:
my_dict = pickle.load(open("outfile.p", "rb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

@jakub @circuito is right 
csv is hard to store list
you can use JSON or pickle

#### if you wana use csv anyway

it can be convert to string, such as :

```
abcd:0|dwg:1|sdgwa:7
```